# How do I fix the tempertature differences between 3 floors in my house?

Tags: hvac, ducts, ventilation, temperature, zoned-heating

In my ~5000 square foot house, the finished basement is very cold, A/C set point stays spot on the main/ground level at 76F, but both upper loft areas 80-84 on hot days!

It is a full height 2 story ceiling with two loft areas. One over the kitchen, and the other over the master bed/bath/1st bedroom at the other side of the house. It is connected with a bridge to keep the living/dining room fully open allowing all the heat to easily rise bringing it over 80 degrees on hot days.

The loft is used as a 'home office' but really gets nearly too hot in the summer while the basement is SO cold it is too cold for most people.

There are 3 fans at top of the highest point of the open high ceiling areas - I have them set in 'reverse' & medium speed... hoping to 'suck up' cool air??

Not sure if this is good for summer or not. Ran them in normal down draft thru last winter and temps were very even thru the entire house (within 2 degrees) even during minus 20F cold winter days.

The tall ceilings seem to be causing so much heat in hot summer days to rise up and just get stuck up there.

Turning the AC down just makes the basement even colder but doesn't seem to cool the upper loft areas much if at all.

I have all 'return air to furnace/ac' vents fully open and not blocked by anything thru the entire house.

I have all 'cold air output vents' fully open in the loft areas and on ground level of the house. I have the basement 'air out vents' fully CLOSED everywhere. So it seems to only be getting cooled by the air falling down the stairway from the main level.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can warm up the basement and cool down the upper loft areas to make things more comfortable? I'm tempted to block off some of the hot air return vents in the loft and force the AC to pull more cool air from the basement but I'm worried that might choke off the flow and end up freezing the coils or something bad to the AC system.

The only other ideas I have been able to come up with would be to add some type of inline 'boost fan' to the output ducts that run up all the way to the loft area just so the most cold air gets up there?

Also, I've thought about closing some of the ground level output vents. But worried the same problem that I might cause some flow restriction and freeze the coil/damage something. Not sure what (if anything) that I can do to warm up the basement and cool off the upper loft areas so the whole house is more evenly kept in all locations. Any and all input is very much appreciated!

Comment: that is corret, the warm air will rise the cold air will go down in you basement. Tell us bit more about your ac  size/model, do you have zone controls

Comment: was it working before or was it always like that, getting balanced air flor can be tricky, all the warm air from lover floor will rise up, for 5000 sqft you must have at least 5 ton and 60,000 BTU HVAC

Comment: Where is the heat coming from? Theoretically outside air should all be the same temperature to all floors.  Are parts of the house getting **direct sun?** Direct sun lays down about 100W (340 BTU) per square foot - most of which is stopped by the insulation, but still, it's huge and must be accounted for.

Comment: Sounds like you have poor flow balance - or, as is common with heat and AC sharing ducts, you need some major damper readjustments between heating and AC season. Hot will rise and cold will sink - part of the job for the HVAC is to offset that. A poorly designed system will not do well at it. There should be a hot air return for cooling season on the top of the building, for instance - if the returns are at floor level only, they are really only set up for heating, not cooling. Poor HVAC design is, unfortunately, common as dirt. Sometimes setting the fan to run all the time helps.

Comment: Setting the ceiling fans to run in the "normal" (blowing air down) direction may help push some of the warmer air down, heating the main floor (slightly) and causing the thermostat to kick in sooner. Putting a box fan at the top of the basement stairs to help pull the cold basement air up may help some, too. You've closed the vents in the basement, try also closing (some/most) them on the main floor (close one at a time, closing additional if it seems to help), to force most of the cold air to at least start in the loft.

Comment: Can you add a whole house fan venting into the attic, If you have one?

Comment: Make sure the doors to any stairways are open to promote vertical air flow

Comment: Close all returns in the basement and 1st floor. This will force the return to pull hot air. In the winter you do exactly the opposite. If there are no dampers cover them with some newspaper. In either case set the blower to run 24/7.